# Improve eager loading with multiple relationships of the same type

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8, eager-loading

I have the following model:

```php
class Message extends Model
{
    public function sender(): HasOne
    {
        return $this->hasOne(User::class, 'sender_id', 'id');
    }

    public function receiver(): HasOne
    {
        return $this->hasOne(User::class, 'receiver_id', 'id');
    }
}
```

When I do `Message::with(['sender', 'receiver'])->all()`, eager loading executes the following queries:

```sql
SELECT * FROM messages
```

```sql
SELECT * FROM users IN(1, 3, 5)
```

```sql
SELECT * FROM users IN(3, 5, 7)
```

That's *almost* the least redundant way possbile. But it still loads user 3 and user five two times. Is there a way to further improve this using eloquent and eager loading?

Comment: Try this `Message::with(['sender', 'receiver'])->groupby('sender.id','senders.id')->get();`

Comment: @Droid doesnt work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, not really.

The example you provided is an exception, nothing tells that any user will be present in both sender and receiver queries.

You could write some code to change how Eloquent behaves in those case but it's not worth it.

CONS:

- The case is restricted to two or more relation eager loaded on the same entity.
- You need to attach the results you removed back to the second query with the right **Order** it should be in.
- might cost way more performance in the code than what it saves from the database.

Comment: Oh, okay. Do really think, it adds more overhead than it avoids?

Comment: @shaedrich imagine it like this `with(['sender' => function ($query) { $query->orderBy('nick_name')->orderBy('first_name');}])` now you have to replace the results that you removed into the list and respect the order desired. You will need the logic of your databse in your PHP code :)

Comment: I'm afraid, I didn't get your point. As long as I don't have any function attached to that relation in the `with()` parameter array, the queries should be identical.

Comment: @shaedrich you're right, but when developing a feature, it needs to be valid with all other features and not be an exception. Or you will end up with a lot of `if()` and a huge mess to debug.

Comment: you're right. Thanks for that food for thought (Y)

Answer (score 0):

### Try these

First replace your `foreignKey` and `localKey`.

class Message extends Model

```
{
    public function sender(): HasOne
    {
        return $this->hasOne(User::class, 'sender_id', 'id');
    }

    public function receiver(): HasOne
    {
        return $this->hasOne(User::class, 'receiver_id', 'id');
    }
}
```

And then use this model query

```
return Message::query()->with(['sender', 'receiver'])->get()
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort but besides correcting my pseudo code it does exactly the same as my code. It doesn't improve eager loading.